# c++ difference between x++ and x = x + 1 when dereferencing iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, increment

I am wondering if someone could explain me the difference between the increment operator `++` and using `...=... + 1` when dereferencing an iterator. I wrote the following small piece of code to sort numbers in bins of 10:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    vector<unsigned> vec(11,0);
    unsigned num;

    while(cin >> num){
        if(num < 100)
            *(vec.begin() + num/10) = *(vec.begin() + num/10) + 1;
        else ;
    }

    for(vector<unsigned>::iterator it = vec.begin();  it != vec.end(); it++)
        cout << *it << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I change the following part of this code:

```
*(vec.begin() + num/10) = *(vec.begin() + num/10) + 1;
```

to:

```
*(vec.begin() + num/10)++;
```

The code doesn't work anymore. Namely the amount of numbers in each bin stays 0.

Could someone explain me the difference between these two lines of code? Is it due to the order of operations? Maybe it increments first then dereferences? But if so I don't understand why.

btw: I used the latest version of g++ in c++98 mode

Comment: Did you try `(*(vec.begin() + num/10))++;`?

Comment: [Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Also preincrement is always better, if you don't need old value

Comment: Thanks 101010 that seems to explain things. My question seems rather dumb now, would it be better if i remove or edit it ? Sorry, i'm new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @MaraJade: It's not dumb if you got useful answer(s) and learned something. Don't forget to accept the answer you found most helpful.

Comment: I will, but apparently I have to wait a few minutes before I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`++` has a higher precedence than `*`, so your expression is parsed like this:

```
*((vec.begin() + num/10)++); //increment, then dereference
```

You'll need to make the ordering explicit:

```
(*(vec.begin() + num/10))++;
```

Note that pre-increment doesn't require a copy, so is generally preferable if you don't need access to the previous value:

```
++(*(vec.begin() + num/10));
```

That said, the line is pretty noisy and unclear, I would split up the expression if I were you:

```
if(num < 100){
    auto position = vec.begin() + num/10;
    ++(*position);
}
```

Or even better (suggested by [@dascandy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272708/dascandy)):

```
if (num < 100) {
    ++vec[num/10];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped alot.

Comment: I'd change the final result to `auto& count = vec[num/10]; count++;`; that also removes the need to dereference in the line after.

Comment: Looking at that line, you could just merge them and do `vec[num/10]++;`. Pretty small, clear & explicit.

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow, it's always rewarding when we can help a poor, aloof alot. Those critters need all the help they can get!